# Why does the same Mathematica demonstration running on Windows/CDF plugin return different values when run on linux CDF player?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I was just trying the CDF player on linux and was comparing how the [same demo](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RigidBodyPendulumOnAFlywheel/) looks using the CDF plugin on windows.  I noticed something strange. Same demo, same initial values, but on windows, the same value shows as zero, while on linux it shows as 3.598 * 10^-19

This is a bit annoying, I hope that one does not have to test a Mathematica CDF on windows and mac and linux to make sure they work the same. I assumed things ought to be the same, other than appearance which might be different due to different OS styles and such. But shouldn't the numerical values be the same?

Here is a screen shot.

[image]

Comment: What is the question though? see the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's hard to say what's happening. In any case, you should always clean up the output using [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberForm.html).

Comment: @Simon, well, yes, I am sure it is easy to 'fix', but that is not the point really. I meant one would expect an identical result to show up from the same CDF.

Comment: Probably a result from using machine-precision numbers on two different machines. Machine-precision calculations are not guaranteed to yield the exact same result on all platforms.

Comment: @acl. No question really. I just thought something is wrong somewhere, and this will be interest to some. After all, this is a  Mathematica group?

Comment: @nasser At Stackoverflow people are rather strict on what makes a correct posting. You should always try to phrase your posting as a question; don't forget this is a Q&A site. That the post is about Mathematica one way or another is not sufficient.

Comment: @Nasser - actually, it's not a Mathematica group. And your last couple of questions are quite likely to be closed by other users of Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Nasser - for non-programming questions (and more for your other question about the Linux firefox plugin), I guess http://superuser.com/ is more appropriate than here

Comment: @acl Thanks for the SuperUser link.  I knew about the site, but had somehow figured it was for system administratortype people/questions.

Comment: @Simon: I think the demonstration is using `NumberForm`, otherwise you wouldn't see `0.000`.  Probably better in this case to use a two-argument `Round`.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite normal.  Different hardware will produce different floating point results.  Note that even if we only consider Intel x86 CPUs, there are several ways to do floating point maths at several precisions, all of which might produce slightly different results.  Even just using different compilers with their different floating point libraries, or using different compiler optimization flags might easily give you slightly different floating point results.  And of course Mathematica was compiled with different compilers on different platforms.

You can use `Chop` to replace close-to-zero machine precision numbers with 0.

If you do numerical calculations on a computer, you must be aware of this.